# Mongodb connection limit is per shard or per cluster?

Tags: mongodb

I haven't found an answer to this question, so if you know where feel free to point me in that direction. But I'm considering mongodb for use in a mobile backend database, but I'm concerned with the concurrent connection limits for each cluster tier in Atlas. Are those limits applied to the entire cluster, or each shard within the cluster has its own connection limit, and those are distributed automatically by the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application does not connect to shards, hence the shards should not see a large number of connections.

In my testing the limit in replica set topologies is per node.